How might I convert the protobuf text encoding of a bytes field to raw binary?
Based on the protobuf text format, the protobuf text representation for a bytes fields is a byte-wise escaped string that in practice includes a mix of raw characters (including characters like $) and different escapes sequences that look like they might be octal or hex:
"\n$e6b7(\215\363\267\230\020\022\rL\032\rMSE\"\rL20\001:\017@\300\213\307\370\2662H\001P\002h\006Z\234\001foobar\n\n/u/p\310\006\232\001\005" 

How might I convert this to raw binary on stdout?

Using which programming language?

Any programming language or command line tool or pseudo-code even.
This question is focused on "what is the algorithm for parsing this encoding" and optimistically hoping here's an existing tool or API in some language that will parse this.

The format uses C string escape sequences. Many tools and libraries can handle these, such as echo -e or Python x.decode('string-escape'). However there are small variations in how the escape sequences are implemented in various systems, so it requires testing or checking to make sure every valid sequence from Protobuf standard is handled.
So we can check what protobuf libraries themselves use:

C++: custom code in io::Tokenizer::ParseStringAppend. Though encoding side uses Abseil CEscape, so one could expect Abseil CUnescape to work. The libprotobuf also exports UnescapeCEscapeString(), which is strangely separate implementation but could be expected to work.
Python: python-protobuf provides google.protobuf.text_encoding.CUnescape() function

